# Is there some application for Twitter that show my updates in real-time?

Tags: windows, twitter

I want to enter my username and see updates constantly from my account. What applications could I use for that on Windows 7?

I want to be able to change the font-size, I want to put in a big display.

Comment: Operating System?

Comment: @Daniel Windows 7...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[TweetDeck Desktop](http://www.tweetdeck.com/) has implemented [Twitter's Streaming API](http://dev.twitter.com/pages/streaming_api), the program will be populated in real-time.